# How do you view Face Sets in Edit Mode?

Tags: 3d-view

In sculpt mode, I can see the Face Sets being highlighted

[image: highlighting in sculpt mode]

but when I switch over to Edit Mode I lose all highlights

[image: no highlighting in edit mode]

is possible to view the Face Set highlighting in any mode other than Sculpt mode? If so how do I turn that feature?

Comment: I think face sets is only for Sculpt mode

Comment: @Emir I have sinking feeling that your right, I'm a novice in blender so, get disorientated when I lose the highlighting from the facesets